# Compare if all elements are equal

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I need to check if all the elements on my dict are equal.

I'm trying with this (1,1,1,1) just to see if it will run, but it always gives me "

```py
Traceback (most recent call last): line 3, in <module>
    if all(sum["lines"]) == sum["lines"][0]:
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

can somebody show me where the problem is?
maybe a little help how can i solve this in a easier way

```
sum = {"lines": {1,1,1,1}}

if all(sum["lines"])== sum["lines"][0]:
    print('they all are {}'.format(sum["lines"][0]))
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Did you mean:’sum = {"lines": (1,1,1,1), "columns": (1,1,1,1)}’?

Comment: This isn't the cause of your error, but that isn't how `all` works. You error is caused by trying to index into a `set` object, which is what you created with `{1,1,1,1}`. You likely meant to create a `list` object.

Comment: like i said, i'm learning and i was pretty sure that would work

Comment: is there a way to do that compare the set?

Comment: So does your dict contain sets or tuples?

Comment: Assuming you got Sets: `sum = {"lines": {1,1,1,1}, "columns": {1,1,1,1}}`, you can use the regular comparison operator: `sum['lines'] == sum['columns']`

Comment: i'm sorry, i i shouldn't had put the "columns".

Comment: i'll update the question to become clear

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using sets it can be done easily:

```
if len(sum['linhas']) ==1:
    print('they are all equal')
```

If the values are stored in a list then:

```
if len(set(sum['linhas'])) == 1:
    print('they are equal')
```

Or

```
if sum['linhas'].count(sum['linhas'][0]) == len(sum['linhas']):
     print('they are equal')
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but isn't Len() just for know the number of elements on the list?

Comment: You don’t have any lists.

Comment: Hey @quamrana, since you said that, i've gone to google about Len on the set and discovered that if i use it the return is the number of different elements.
Thanks a LOT to quamrana Shadowcodder for the help, you guys are amazing!!!!!!

Comment: Excellent news. So, did you mean to use sets, tuples or lists inside your dict? I’m asking this on behalf of all the future readers of this question to remove confusion.

Comment: I think my goal was to use sets really.
I'm using it just to put all the sums of lines, columns and diagonals of a matrix, so i can compare if all of then are all equal.
its a Sudoku solver haha.

Comment: If you are using a set, then {1,1,1,1} becomes {1}, thus it’s len is 1.

Comment: I've discovered that my goal was really to use lists inside the dict.

Comment: @Juan Almeida I have updated the answer so it will now work for list.

Answer (score 1):

because you're using sets, you can easily do:

```
sum = {"lines": {1,1,1,1}, "columns": {1,1,1,1}}
if len(sum["lines"]) == 1:
  print('they all are {}'.format(sum["lines"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there I'm new here too but would still like to help you solve this. In my opinion, the keyword of the dictionary is "lines" but you are using "linhas" in the if statement. Also you would simply use an if statement like this:

```
sums = {"lines": {1,1,1,1}, "columns": {1,1,1,1}}
if sums["lines"] == sums["columns"]:
    print("They are equal")
```

Comment: It was a honest mistake on "linhas" and "lines", im sorry, i was coding using portuguese so when i came to stackoverflow i tried to change to english but forgot the other one hahaha.
Also, what i wanted was to know if all in "lines" are equals among each other, "columns" wasn't even to be there hahaha.

Comment: I'm sorry I misinterpreted your question. I thought you wanted to check if they are equal among each other. Same here, honest mistake.

Comment: When you use {} in python like in this case {1,1,1,1} it is a set. To make a list you have to use [] like [1,1,1,1] Edit: to make your code work you just have to remove 'all' and change it from set to list.